# watching and usingf webrtc stream in angular app directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, webrtc

Implementing a webrtc based webapp using angular 1.x. The webrtc related functionality is abstracted within a service and the controller watches the variables in the service.

Within the service, when I set the stream (either local or remote) using $rootScope.$apply(), the watch function in the controller gets executed. However at the same time, I see the following error on the console.

```
vendor.44edef6c.js:5 TypeError: Illegal invocation
at P (vendor.44edef6c.js:3)
at P (vendor.44edef6c.js:3)
at P (vendor.44edef6c.js:3)
at o.$digest (vendor.44edef6c.js:6)
at o.$apply (vendor.44edef6c.js:6)
at scripts.d348f551.js:6
at Object.w [as emit] (scripts.d348f551.js:1)
at scripts.d348f551.js:2
```

This in only seen if I try to set the video element source, not when I make an audion webrtc call. Are there any issues when passing a webrtc stream object from the service and using? Below is the html

```
<video ng-src="{{localStream}}" autoplay muted></video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some issue if you try to watch the webrtc stream from the controller since the stream object is quite complex and huge. So instead convert it to a URL string using `URL.createObjectURL()` and then call `$apply()`. By doing this, I was able to get around the errors.

In addition, as @adrian-ber suggested either `$sce.trustAsResourceUrl()` either in the service or in the controller.

The core issue seems to be watching the stream object. Avoid it.

Comment: Watching stream is causing it to break somehow. If you manually call $apply and user src={{url}} instead of ng-src it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's because that stream URL is not a trusted one. You have to do something like this:

```
localStream = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(window.URL.createObjectURL(localStream));
```

Comment: I have tried it, but didn't help. This console error is thrown in the service when it does the $rootScope.$apply().

Comment: Have you tried $safeApply() instead of $apply()? https://github.com/yearofmoo/AngularJS-Scope.SafeApply